# Is there a Fraps-like recording application for Ubuntu with microphone support?

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast, video-recording

Is there a program that works like [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)? I specifically would like to have these features:

1. The record hotkey.
2. Microphone support.
3. And the ability to change the video output folder.

Answer (score 3):

[Simple Screen Recorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder) has all the [features](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/#features) that you are looking for.

[image]
[image]
[image]

To install -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

Comment: Can it do this at the quality FRAPS can? FRAPS is commonly used to record high FPS games.

Comment: @Seth There is an option to record OpenGL, and hence recording most games should be possible. There is a video demo on the project website.